# Scala design pattern with implicit parameter (Play 2.x in Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, implicit

I am working on a play 2.1 project and need some guidance on a scala design problem. 
For our application, a request context object which stores client information from the incoming request is needed at the model layer.

```
case class ClientContext(clientName: String) 

object ClientContext {
  def apply(request: Request) = {
    new ClientContext(request.params("clientName")) //pseudo code
  }
}
```

my model

```
object MyDAO {
  def findAll(context: ClientContext) = { ... }
}
```

Then in our controller, we need to pass it into model's dao method:

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  def index = Action { implicit request => 
    val results = MyDAO.findAll(ClientContext(request))
    Ok(results)
  }
}
```

The `implicit request` is provided by the `Action` class (I suppose) The problem with this approach is that I need to write `implicit request =>` and `ClientContext(request)` for every controller action that calls MyDAO.findAll.

Is there a way to improve the code through an Action wrapper and implicit value? I would like to be able to declare `context: ClientContext` as an implicit parameter in the `MyDAO.findAll` method and write my actions in the following way:

```
object MyDAO {
  def findAll(implicit context: ClientContext) = { ... }
}

def index = ActionWithContext {
  val results = MyDAO.findAll
  Ok(results)
}
```

Is it possible to write an ActionWithContext (method or object with an apply method) to achieve that?  The closest I have now is the following

```
def ActionWithContext(action: ClientContext => Result) = {
  Action { implicit request =>
    action(ClientContext(request))
  }
}
```

usage

```
def index = ActionWithContext { context => 
  val results = MyDAO.findAll(context)
  Ok(results)
}
```

Any suggestion to improve this design will be helpful. Thanks!

PS: Honestly I wouldn't even think about further simplifying the code if this is on Java, but since it's scala, I figured it might be good chance to learn some scala patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented something similar using implicits:

I call mine `Header` instead of `Context` but we're both accomplishing the same thing.

All of my controllers mixin the `Header` trait:

```
object Accounts extends AuthController with Header { ... }
```

My `Header` trait looks something like this:

```
trait Header {
    implicit def withUserInfo(implicit maybeUser: Option[User]): UserInfo = {
        // create user info object
    }
}
```

Then I can write my controller actions like so:

```
def index = MaybeAuthenticated { implicit maybeUser => implicit request =>
    // do stuff
    val foo = new Foo()
    Ok(views.html.accounts.index(foo))
}
```

Where the template has a method signature like so:

```
@(foo: Foo)(implicit userInfo: UserInfo)
```

`MaybeAuthenticated` is just an action which optionally restores a `User` object, it's from the play20-auth module.  In fact, I've shown you two possibilities here:

1. Mixin a trait with an implicit function which takes implicit parameters.
2. Write your own action method like `MaybeAuthenticated`

`MaybeAuthenticated` looks like this:

```
private def maybeAuthenticated(f: Option[Account] => Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action(BodyParsers.parse.anyContent)(req => f(restoreUser(req))(req))
}

protected def MaybeAuthenticated = maybeAuthenticated _
```

I would argue that the first method is easier to understand.

edit: I think some further explanation of implicits is warranted.

Let's consider where `implicit` is used above:

#### implicit def withUserInfo(implicit maybeUser: Option[User]): UserInfo

In an object that mixes in `Header`, this method will be in scope.  The compiler will search for functions which require a `UserInfo` object to be in scope where a `Option[User]` is already in scope.  The compiler will *implicitly* call `withUserInfo` to provide the missing `UserInfo` object.

Note the implicit `UserInfo` object required by my template.  When I call this template function (the `Ok(...)` invocation), the compiler has to fill in the implicit `UserInfo` object.  It will do so by calling `withUserInfo` and passing the in-scope implicit `maybeUser`.

Hope that clarifies implicits a little.

Comment: Ryan, thanks very much for this really detailed answer. It seems that it's going to take some time for me to get my head around it.

Comment: I've added a short explanation of implicits, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks  Ryan, please forgive my slowness with scalait was mostly the curried  action fiction that confused me the most

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ryan's suggestion here is the another solution
In ClientContext object make the apply method also an implicit conversion that takes in an implicit parameter

```
object ClientContext {
  implicit def apply(implicit request: Request) = {
    new ClientContext(request.params("clientName")) //pseudo code
  }
}
```

Then in the controller you can write

```
def index = Action { implicit request => 
  val results = MyDAO.findAll
  Ok(results)
}
```

I am not sure if there is way to get rid of the `implicit request` but this is pretty terse to me now.

Comment: The `implicit request` is still required.  You have to bring the request into scope.